# Why should I use SqlCommand.CommandType = StoredProcedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

**Question:** What is the difference between using a standard `SQLCommand` and `SQLCommand.ComandType = StoredProcedure`?

Since I'm not sure if parameters are passed to the command object *by name* or *by order*, I prefer this:

```
SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand("exec sp_StoredProcedure @Param1, @Param2, @Param3", oDBConnection);
oCmd.Parameters.Add("Param1", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = var_param1;
oCmd.Parameters.Add("Param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = var_param2;
oCmd.Parameters.Add("Param3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = var_param3;
```

rather than

```
SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_StoredProcedure", oDBConnection);
oCmd.CommandType = StoredProcedure;
oCmd.Parameters.Add("Param1", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = var_param1;
oCmd.Parameters.Add("Param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = var_param2;
oCmd.Parameters.Add("Param3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = var_param3;
//Do the parameter names and the parameter order matter here?
```

I don't understand why I should do the second?

Comment: It seems to me there's less duplication and less room for error with the second, for one thing... *why* do you prefer the first?

Comment: SQL Server can be slightly more efficient in its query plan cache. The former would require two query plan cached per sproc.

Comment: @JonSkeet because I couldn't find enough documentation about the second(see the comment under the 2nd code block), and I have to update code where the sp_Name is a variable, and the different sp_ have slightly different parameters. The code at the moment uses the second, but I feel inclined to move to the first because I understand it better.

Comment: @RafaelCichocki resist that inclination; it is, IMO, a very very bad idea

Comment: @RafaelCichocki the "by order / by name" is a feature of how you are using `exec` in your inner TSQL, not the choice of `CommandType`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first is a completely redundant step, that forces a second (but trivial) query-plan to be parsed, generated, cached and executed. It also offers great opportunity to mess up by (for example) forgetting to add the parameters. You also need to consider that the parameters in the first are now passed *by position* (in the inner TSQL), where-as in the second they are passed *by name*; by name is usually preferable here. Likewise, if you add a new parameter to `oCmd.Parameters` you now have an extra maintenance step of maintaining the inner command - or risk introducing bugs, where-as in the second example *you don't need to do anything extra*.

Basically, the first example has nothing at all positive, and lots of negative points.

---

Re pass-by-name versus pass-by-position, this is basically a feature of the `exec` keyword in TSQL. There are two uses:

```
exec MyProc 'abc', 123
```

or

```
exec MyProc @foo='abc', @bar=123
```

The first is by-position; `'abc'` is passed to the first declared parameter of `MyProc`, and `123` is passed to the second declared parameter of `MyProc`. Any additional parameters assume their default values if they have one.

The second is by-name; `'abc'` is passed to the parameter of `MyProc` called `@foo`, and `123` is passed to the parameter of `MyProc` called `@bar`. Any other parameters assume their default values if they have one.

So in your specific example:

```
exec sp_StoredProcedure @Param1, @Param2, @Param3
```

is pass-by-position, and:

```
exec sp_StoredProcedure @Param1=@Param1, @Param2=@Param2, @Param3=@Param3
```

is bass-by-name.

Comment: Ah ok - the *by name* vs *by position* was crucial information I was missing. I will stick to using `CommandType = stored procedure`.

Comment: @RafaelCichocki note: you *could* pass-by-name in the inner SQL - but it makes it even more verbose to maintain (and more prone to copy/paste errors): `"exec sp_StoredProcedure @Param1=@Param1, @Param2=@Param2, @Param3=@Param3"` - frankly, compared to simply `"sp_StoredProcedure"`, I know which I would choose. BTW: IIRC official guidance is to **NOT** use prefixes like `sp_`

Comment: sorry, I'm confused now. So what exactly determines whether parameters are taken by order or by name? How would I have to write the code to differentiate between both cases? If you could extend your answer by an example of both cases that would be great.

Comment: @RafaelCichocki will edit

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the [microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ...the names of the parameters added to the Parameters collection must match the names of the parameter markers in the stored procedure.

So if I use the same code with `CommandType = StoredProcedure` for different stored procedures, then I need to make sure for each stored procedure possibly executed, that it gets only those parameters in the [parameter collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that are named the same as in the stored procedure to be executed.